# Learning Python and Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to learn Scrapy and Python. I'm having an issue I don't understand. I'm running the same piece of code once through the Terminal and then again through a script and the results are different. The Terminal gives me all the titles (what I want) the script just gives me the first.

```
for title in response.css('div.section-content ul'):
     item = {
             'title' : title.css('li h3 a::text').extract_first(),
            }
```

I'm trying to extract all the movie names on the iTunes movies page.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
import scrapy


class ItunesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'itunes'
    allowed_domains = ['apple.com']
    start_urls = ['apple.com/itunes/charts/movies/']

    def parse(self, response):

        self.log ('I just visited: ' + response.url)
        for title in response.css('div.section-content ul'):
            item = { 'title' : title.css('li h3 a::text').extract_first(), }
            yield item
```

Comment: Is this the exact same formatting as in your script?

Comment: hey could you give us an example from the output of script and terminal?

Comment: You MUST have a `yield item` inside of the for loop, and not outside. If the `yield` is outside of the for loop, the spider will only yield the last item.

Comment: The code given doesn't output anything. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: So when I use the script in the terminal I get a list of movies, when I output the script to json I just get the first movie.

Comment: When you say Inside the loop you mean inside the brackets? if I put the yield inside the brackets I get an SyntaxError: invalid syntax error.

Comment: This is right from my script

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ItunesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'itunes'
    allowed_domains = ['apple.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.apple.com/itunes/charts/movies/']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log ('I just visited: ' + response.url)

        for title in response.css('div.section-content ul'):
            item = {
                'title' : title.css('li h3 a::text').extract_first(),
         }

         yield item

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple thought error in your CSS-Selector; where you are looping through all items of type `ul` (and there is only one of that). What you want, is to loop through the `li` elements instead.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class ItunesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'itunes'
    allowed_domains = ['apple.com']
    start_urls = ['https://apple.com/itunes/charts/movies/']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log ('I just visited: ' + response.url)
        for title in response.css('div.section-content ul li'):
            title = title.css('h3 a::text').extract_first()
            self.log('Title: %s' % title)
            item = { 
                'title' : title,
            }   
            yield item
```

Why it works differently for you "in the terminal", I do not know.